# How to rename multiple files using find and rename

Tags: find, rename

I want to take out .hs from all files. Why this command doesn`t work properly?
It leaves the same name of files.

```
find . -type f -exec rename .hs ' ' * \;
```

Comment: Try: `find . -type f -exec rename .hs '' {} \;`.  If that doesn't work, tell us which of the various and incompatible versions of the command `rename` is the one that you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
find . -type f -exec rename .hs ' ' * \;
```

With:

```
find . -type f -exec rename .hs '' {} \;
```

In an `-exec` command, the place where you want your file name to go should be marked with `{}`.

Also, as I am guessing that you want `.hs` removed, not replaced with a space, we have removed the space between the single-quotes.

#### Documentation

`man find` includes an explanation of the `-exec` option:

> **-exec command ;**
>    Execute command; true if 0 status is
>   returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments
>   to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered. 
>   **The string `{}`  is  replaced  by  the  current  file name being
>   processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command**, not
>   just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find. 
>   Both of these constructions might need to be escaped  (with a `\`) or
>   quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.  See the EXAMPLES
>   section for examples of the use of the -exec option.  The specified
>   command is run once for each matched file.  The command is   executed
>   in the starting directory.   There are unavoidable security problems
>   surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the `-execdir`
>   option instead. [Emphasis added.]

Answer (score 1):

Using [Shell (Ksh, Bash, ksh93, mksh, zsh) Pattern substitution expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${var/Pattern/Replacement}` (First match of *Pattern*, within *var* replaced with *Replacement*. Or `${var//Pattern/Replacement}`; **Global replacement**. All matches of *Pattern*, within *var* replaced with *Replacement*. If *Replacement* is omitted, then the match(es) of *Pattern* is replaced by *nothing*, that is, deleted.)

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1/.sh/}"' _ {} \;
```

Ps, remove `echo` to rename on file.